# Translation of "account for"

Tags: traduction, anglais, science

What is the most adequate interpretation of *account for* in contexts like:

> The proposed hierarchical micromechanics scheme **accounts for** viscoelastic matrix response.

Does ***prendre en compte***, as follows,

> *Le schéma de micromécanique hiérarchique proposé **prend en compte** la réponse matricielle viscoélastique.*

suit here?

Comment: You should better explain the expected meaning of "accounts for" here. *Account for* can be translated either by ***tient compte de/prend en compte*** or by ***représente***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The proposed hierarchical micromechanics scheme **accounts for** viscoelastic matrix response.

From this I gather that the proposed scheme, among other positive features that are left aside in this sentence in particular, will either :

- explain in a simpler manner or in a more robust framework some pre-existing experimental results at this time put together as a matrix ; *or...*
- have included these pre-existing results as an intrinsic part of its construction.

In the first case (a simpler or more robust explanation or presentation of the existing viscoelastic matrix response), French could say :

- Le schéma de micromécanique hiérarchisé proposé **explique** la matrice de réponse viscoélastique.

On the other hand, if the second explanation is the right one, then the following could convey the idea in French :

- Le schéma de micromécanique hiérarchisé proposé **tient compte de** la matrice de réponse viscoélastique.
- Le schéma de micromécanique hiérarchisé proposé **inclut** la matrice de réponse viscoélastique.

Answer (score 0):

« to account for » signifie « expliquer ».

COMPLÉMENT [suscité par ce commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/32254/translation-of-account-for/32258?noredirect=1#comment75587_32258)
Je ne comprends pas exactement tous les phénomènes mais les déductions suivantes semblent avoir du sens.

Considérons cet article ;

[modèle viscoélastique de réponse des mousses polymériques à la compression cyclique](http://documents.irevues.inist.fr/bitstream/handle/2042/37033/313.pdf)

Il y est question de viscoélasticité pour le modèle de réponse

Dans le même article on trouve ceci ;

> Dans le modèle de Mullins et Tobin [14],
>   la perte de résistance est attribuée à la rupture des liaisons entre la **matrice** polymérique et les particules de carbone. En se basant sur cette idée, beaucoup de modèles, qui décrivent macroscopiquement la rupture des liaisons avec une variable d’endommagement, ont été proposés [2, 3, 10, 12].

[encyclopédie libre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrice_(constituant))

> De façon générale, dans un matériau composite, une matrice (plastique, métal, céramique ou leurs combinaisons) est une matière servant de liant et à transférer les efforts au renfort (fibres, billes, microsphères, etc.), qui est plus rigide et plus résistant.
>   Dans les composites à matrice organique (plastiques renforcés), elle est appelée résine.

Il serait donc question d'un modèle viscoélastique de réponse de la matrice.

[modélisation micromécanique](https://hal.univ-lorraine.fr/tel-01752682/document)

> Durant  les  trois  dernières  décennies,  de  nombreux  travaux  dédiés  à  la  plasticité  des  matériaux polycristallins  (Taylor [TAY 34], Lin [LIN 57], Hill [HIL 65], Lipinski [LIP 89]), ont mis en évidence les avantages  de  l’approche  micromécanique  par  rapport  à  l’approche  classique  de  la  loi  de  comportement.

Des simulations numériques utilisant des lois de comportement phénoménologiques ont montré que ce type de lois ne permettait pas d’obtenir des résultats satisfaisants, en comparaison avec des essais expérimentaux   réalisés   en   parallèle (p. 13)

[viscoélasticité](https://www.editions.polytechnique.fr/files/pdf/EXT_1557_2.pdf)

> Dans la première partie, la simplicité du modèle mécanique permet l’introduction phénoménologique des concepts fondamentaux de la viscoélasticité à partir des expériences essentielles de retard et de relaxation. La loi de comportement viscoélastique apparaît comme une correspondance fonctionnelle entre l’histoire de la sollicitation et l’histoire de la réponse (p. 4)

Le modèle micro mécanique hiérarchique serait donc un modèle plus précis que le modèle de comportement appelé viscoélasticité ou le modèle exact, fondé sur les causes premières, et il *expliquerait* la viscoélasticité en cela que les résultats obtenus correspondent essentiellement ; en quelque sorte le modèle micro mécanique hiérarchique *justifierait* le modèle viscoélastique de réponse de la matrice.

Comment: Could you elaborate more? Thanks!